# Why file isn't opening C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying this code for a few first times only. I am not able to get to the root of the error.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("C:\\Users\\AfzaalAhmad\\Documents\\text.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

The file is present at the location. Here is a screenshot of the file system.

[image: Screenshot of the file system]

There is no exception in this case, but the file is never opened!

Where am I missing code?

Comment: Do you need the double back-slashes? Shouldn't it be something like C:\path\to\my\file ?

Comment: @sergico I need to escape the backslash .. since when I use single slash it gives error!

Comment: The double backslashes are necessary, the first makes the second literal

Comment: Try forward slashes? Supposedly windows compilers will recognise either in full file paths. By the way, I assume you're running some test to check that it's not open?

Comment: How do you check if the file is open?

Comment: How do you *know* the file doesn't open? You don't check for it?

Comment: @chrisb2244 it doesn't work either! Forward slash..

Comment: No I don't, I just check whether there is a new file opened or not. isn't that the way ??

Comment: It doesn't open in notepad or something you know - you just have a fstream object inside the C++ program that lets you read it from there.  For example, ou can then say `std::string line; while (getline(file, line)) std::cout << line << '';` to write the file content to the stdout (terminal) (you'd need to `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>` for that too.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Out of interest, what did you think would happen? And which book are you using?

Comment: No book, this site: tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus I thought I could open a file like double clicking on it! I misunderstood...@LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Yeah, you should definitely learn from a book, not "tuts" on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you've written will open a handle to a file at that location. In order to do anything with it, you'll need some sort of read or write operation. Probably your code is working fine :)

For example, following your `file.open("...")` line:

```
file << "This is some text to send to my now open file\n";
...
file.close();
```

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer with some examples - the other answer from @karakale is likely to be helpful for you there :)

Comment: I would have tried out his tutorial link, but I don't know why that site is down since 3 days here: http://imgur.com/RveTZfP ..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: No, you should use [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Well, I confess to having used cplusplus.com quite a bit, but I'm told it's not very good. As @LightnessRacesinOrbit points out, SO has a question about the best C/C++ books with some pretty extensive answers.

Comment: @chrisb2244: The reference, nowadays, is fairly accurate and well maintained, but the forum contributions are not inherently peer reviewed, and because of the name of the site you get a _lot_ of entry-level contributions that will teach you bad practices and bugs, written by those who don't yet know any better. It's a vicious cycle, really. The tutorial is _okay_, but no substitute for a full book written by a prestigious author.